# CSS Smooth fade and out transition (including text)

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a simple hover effect that changes the text and background. What I would like to know is if there is a possible way to slow down the fade effect... I'm sure you can using the transition css but I have little knowledge on how to use it.

(The code is not full code and does not work correctly (but should be enough))

Here is HTML:

```
<div id="ourproductsleft" class="grid_3 alpha">
       <h4>Mail</h4>
       <img class="replies" src="img/index/body/ourproducts/mail_accept.png"/>
       <p class="comment">Packed with features and backed by our 1st class technical support, Data Connectivity email hosting is the smart choice for both personal and business users.</p>
       <br>
       <br>
       <p class="comment2"> <a href="<%= url_prefix %>hosting.html">For more Information on our <u>Mail</u> service.</a> </p>         
       </div> <!--end of ourproductsleft class 3-->
```

Here is CSS

```
/*Backgrounds for each div*/
#ourproductsleft {
background: #F2F7FA;
/*background-image:url(../img/index/body/ourproducts/grey.png);
background-repeat:repeat;*/
border-radius: 0px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;   
}

/*Hover bacgrounds for each div*/
#ourproductsleft:hover {
background-  image:url(../img/index/body/ourproducts/light_blue_background_pattern.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;
}


/*Do not display original (mail, domain etc) text on hover view*/
#ourproductsleft:hover .replies { 
display: none;

}

/*Keep display inline for maintext (longtext) on hover */
#ourproductsleft:hover .comment { 
display: inline;
opacity: 1; 
}
```

I have also made a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8kW7y/)

Comment: You can add 'transition: all 1.6s ease-in-out;' to the #ourproductsleft:hover

Comment: @RobertVerkerk I just tried it and it doesn't seem to make any difference. Is this what you meant? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kW7y/2/)

Comment: I can't see the image with the fiddle please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8kW7y/4/ . If you hover over the div you see the background change

Comment: Also, you cannot transition the `display` property.

Comment: @RobertVerkerk I see. Is there a way to slow down the out-effect of the text itself? So when you over away the text slowly fades out?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8kW7y/6/

Comment: @Paulie_D exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, post as an answer so I can close the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8kW7y/6/)

Essentially, you must use opacity with a  transitions rather than `display:none` as the latter is not 'transitionable'. There are other options depending on what effect you are after but this is the basics.

**HTML**

```
<div id="ourproductsleft" class="grid_3 alpha">
    <h4>Mail</h4>
    <img class="replies" src="img/index/body/ourproducts/mail_accept.png"/>

    <p class="comment">Packed with features and backed by our 1st class technical support, Data Connectivity email hosting is the smart choice for both personal and business users.</p>

    <p class="comment2"> <a href="<%= url_prefix %>hosting.html">For more Information on our <u>Mail</u> service.</a> </p>        
</div> <!--end of ourproductsleft class 3-->
```

**CSS**

```
/*Backgrounds for each div*/
#ourproductsleft {
    background: #F2F7FA;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
}


#ourproductsleft .comment,
#ourproductsleft .replies { 
    opacity: 0; 
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

#ourproductsleft:hover .comment,
#ourproductsleft:hover .replies{ 
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you again, this is the exact sort of thing I was looking for. I will find a way to get by without the `display:none` :)

Answer (score 0):

Hiii,
you can add

```
transition-property: width, border-radius, background-color;
transition-duration: 1s, 2s, 5s;
transition-timing-function:  ease, ease-out, linear;
```

in your css

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I make it fade out? So when it's not hovering it would slowly fade out? Is it possible to fade text?

Answer (score 0):

use this transition property in any element on which you are using `:hover` effect.

```
.example {
    transition: [transition-property] [transition-duration] [transition-timing-function] [transition-delay];
}
```

for example :

```
-webkit-transition:2s color;
-moz-transition:2s color;
transition:2s color;
```

Multiple properties can be differentiate by comma

```
transition: 1s background 0.5 ease-in, 2s color 1s ease-out;
```